# C++ CMD Window Output with SDL

Tags: c++, sdl, cout

Is it possible to get the output of COUT in the cmd window, even though you are using SDL? If so, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ / SDL Debugging with console window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482363/c-sdl-debugging-with-console-window)

Comment: Again, just like an hour ago, **please do some research before posting**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution #1:
[FAQ_Console](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/FAQ_Console)

Solution #2:

add
    `#undef main` before `int main(int argc, char** argv)`, and don't link to SDLmain (SDLMain == libSDLMain.a or SDLmain.lib).